# Select2; how to load in an array that I load once from the database

Tags: javascript, arrays, asp.net-mvc, callback, jquery-select2

I am loading an array with the results of the following Action:

```
public ActionResult GetJudges(string q)
    {
        var judges = new List<Judge>();
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "query";
                con.Open();
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        var judge = default(Judge);
                        var id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"]);
                        var email = Convert.ToString(rdr["Email"]);
                        var name = Convert.ToString(rdr["Name"]);
                        var jurisdiction = Convert.ToString(rdr["Jurisdiction"]);
                        var code= Convert.ToString(rdr["code"]);

                        if (!judges.Select(x => x.Id).Contains(id))
                        {
                            judge = new Judge
                            {
                                Id = id,
                                Email = email,
                                Name = name,
                                Code= code
                            };
                            judges.Add(judge);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            judge = judges.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);
                        }

                        judge.Jurisdictions.Add(jurisdiction);
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return Json(judges, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I am trying to load this array into a Select2 element, and having no success. The select2 element is always empty. Here is the javascript I am using to load the select2:

```
var judges = [];


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON('/Home/GetJudges', function (result) {
            judges = result;
            $(".select2").select2({
                placeholder: "Search for a Judge",
                data: { results: result, id: "Id", text: "Text" }
            });
        });
    });
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Use a `console.log` to inspect what your `result` is before you pass it to `select2`

Comment: I get an array of objects:

[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Comment: `return Json(judges.Select(a => new {id = a.Id, text = a.Name}), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: thank you much. that did exactly what I was looking for @JamieD77 if you make it an answer I'll mark it as such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-array) example on how to use select2. You are passing the data incorrectly. Your `result` should contain an array of objects that have an `id` property and a `text` property, and you should be passing that to select2 as `data` directly, rather than wrapping it in another object.

```
//sample data
var result = [{id: 0, text: 'Judge 1'}, {id: 1, text: 'Judge 2'}];

$(".select2").select2({
    placeholder: "Search for a Judge",
    data: result
});
```